# MongoDB ObjectID vs Integer index performance

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-design

Log table consisting millions of records

```
_id
userID
actionTypeID
logDetails
createdAt
```

If we choose `_id` with **int** datatype for `userID` and `actionTypeID` will it show significant performance improvement than **ObjectID** since **ObjectID** weighs 12 bytes and **int32** weighs 4 bytes?

Comment: I don't think there will be any major performance impact between the two. Go with the `ObjectID` method if you don't want to deal with handling unique running sequence and timestamp to be embedded on the `_id` key. Go with `int` method if you will be storing millions of data and want to optimize size in every way possible and don't care about handling the unique int sequence on your backend.

Comment: @hhharsha36 yeah that make sense. The `users` and `actionTypes` table would only have few thousands and few dozens of entries respectively. However the log table will have millions of entries and it wil be required to query the table with userID and actionTypeID.

Comment: This is an interesting scenario. In that case, I would recommend you to go with `ObjectID` as _id in log collection and index the `userID` key in log collection. Use `int` as `_id` in users collection, that way, the `userID` key in log collection will be human readable. Make the log collection as human readable as possible, that should be your goal.

Comment: I have the same question - and know that Int always matches faster than String - but am not certain about ObjectId (which I believe is a wrapper around hex?) In case it gets a response I have this same question on MondoDB forum here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/objectid-string-or-int-as-primary-key-does-it-matter/105336/2